# how to accept string and Integer using doubly linked list in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I have created a menu driven program using doubly liked list. the program is accepting the integers values. but i want the program which is accept the integer and string both the create a doubly linked list where each node contains  one character of a string and integer. how can i modify the code help me please....? here is my code,

```
package car;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class DoublyLinkedList {
         public static void main(String[] args)
            {            
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                /* Creating object of linkedList */
                linkedList list = new linkedList(); 
                System.out.println("Doubly Linked List Test\n");          
                char ch;
                /*  Perform list operations  */
                do
                {
                    System.out.println("\nDoubly Linked List Operations\n");
                    System.out.println("1. insert at begining");
                    System.out.println("2. insert at end");
                    System.out.println("3. insert at position");
                    System.out.println("4. delete at position");
                    System.out.println("5. check empty");
                    System.out.println("6. get size");

                    int choice = scan.nextInt();            
                    switch (choice)
                    {
                    case 1 : 
                        System.out.println("Enter integer element to insert");
                        list.insertAtStart( scan.nextInt() );                     
                        break;                          
                    case 2 : 
                        System.out.println("Enter integer element to insert");
                        list.insertAtEnd( scan.nextInt() );                     
                        break;                         
                    case 3 : 
                        System.out.println("Enter integer element to insert");
                        int num = scan.nextInt() ;
                        System.out.println("Enter position");
                        int pos = scan.nextInt() ;
                        if (pos < 1 || pos > list.getSize() )
                            System.out.println("Invalid position\n");
                        else
                            list.insertAtPos(num, pos);
                        break;                                          
                    case 4 : 
                        System.out.println("Enter position");
                        int p = scan.nextInt() ;
                        if (p < 1 || p > list.getSize() )
                            System.out.println("Invalid position\n");
                        else
                            list.deleteAtPos(p);
                        break;     
                    case 5 : 
                        System.out.println("Empty status = "+ list.isEmpty());
                        break;            
                    case 6 : 
                        System.out.println("Size = "+ list.getSize() +" \n");
                        break;                         
                    default : 
                        System.out.println("Wrong Entry \n ");
                        break;   
                    }    
                    /*  Display List  */ 
                    list.display();
                    System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue (Type y or n) \n");
                    ch = scan.next().charAt(0);    

                } while (ch == 'Y'|| ch == 'y');               
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you talking about having both `Integer` and `String` datatype as the data for each of your node? If yes, then update your `LinkedList` variable to `LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList()`.

Comment: You instantiate an object of a class unknown to everyone but you: `list = new linkedList()` - difficult to give more specific advice than Zhi Kai.

Answer (score 0):

> where each node contains one character of a string and integer

So you want to have two data-types per node...

You could create your support class `Pair`

```
public class Pair<T, U> {
    private T t;
    private U u;

    // constructors, getters, setters, equals and hashcode ...

    public static <T, U> Pair<T, U> of(final T t, final U u) {
        return new Pair<>(t, u);
    }
}
```

then have

```
final List<Pair<String, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(Pair.of("string", 4));
// ...


Pair<String, Integer> pair = list.get(9);
```